# Typescript not exporting class for requirejs with internal modules

Tags: requirejs, typescript

TYPESCRIPT:

```
import classModule = require("path/to/class");

module my.namespace {
  export class MyClass {
    constructor() {
       var someClass = new classModule.className();
    }
  }
}
```

GENERATED JAVASCRIPT:

```
define(["require", "exports", "path/to/class"], function (require, exports, classModule) {
    var my;
    (function (my) {
        var namespace;
        (function (namespace) {
            var MyClass = (function () {

                function MyClass () {

                    var someClass = classModule.className();

                }
                return MyClass ;
            })();
            namespace.MyClass = MyClass ;
        })(namespace = my.namespace || (my.namespace = {}));
    })(my || (my = {}));
});
```

So, it does not export "MyClass" so it's not available to a module that imports it.

If I remove the typescript

```
module my.namespace
```

it does:

```
. . .
return MyClass;

})();
exports.MyClass= MyClass;
```

How do i get it to export MyClass wrapped with an internal module?

I could export it by hand, but I thought this was supposed to work.
I know the internal module namespace isn't the best, but I have a ton of code wrapped in Typescript modules. I am using Visual Studio and have the AMD flag set for the project. Typescript 1.4. I'm loading "MyClass" with a require(["myclass"]) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `export` the module that contains the class if you want to the module (and its contents) to be exported.

Really though, there's zero reason to have a top-level 'namespace' module in an external module. See "needless namespacing" in the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook)

Comment: I tried that :  export my.namespace { export MyClass {  -- and it did not generate an export

Comment: It does export the object `my.namespace.MyClass`

Comment: yes it does. I missed that - thanks. Is there a recommend typescript module pattern for NOT using requirejs? Do you have to use script tags in that scenario?

Comment: Just remove the `export` keyword from the *top-level* objects and include all the output .js with script tags. You can use `--out` on the commandline in this case to combine your files into one .js file (be careful of ordering issues).